# Tailwind is not loaded in Jetstream Livewire App

Tags: laravel, npm, vite, laravel-livewire

I have a fresh Laravel Jetstream Livewire application, here are the steps I followed to make it so that its hosted on a VPS managed by Plesk<(Please remember its not hosted locally, its hosted on a VPS):

1. `cd` into an empty subdomain folder and then:

   `composer create-project laravel/laravel .`
2. Set up a new DB and connect it in the `.env`
3. `php artisan migrate`
4. `composer require laravel/jetstream`
5. `php artisan jetstream:install livewire --dark`
6. `npm install`
7. `npm run build`
8. `php artisan migrate`

This has created an app successfully. Note that I still have not edited or added any new files, everything is as is.  I can log in, logout, and do the stuff without a problem. I would like to use the `welcome.blade.php` as my starting point. However, the Tailwind styles are inline, a major part of TailwindCSS has been minimized into a 1-liner, lol. So it looks like this `<style>12kCSS Characters</style>` If I remove this  block then there is no CSS applied at all, it's like Tailwind is not even installed. I checked my project structure and here is my tailwind.config.js:

```
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';
import typography from '@tailwindcss/typography';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [forms, typography],
};
```

I use `npm run build` to build my assets and when I run `npm run dev` I get this:

[image]

This is what I get when I use `npm run build`:

[image]

When I use npm run dev, I am not able to type afterwards in the console, its running, but with build its just being built.

So, I use `npm run build` to build my app. These are the only commands that I have(npm run dev & build), I have used these and nothing has changed.
My project structure is like: `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php`
I also have this `/resources/css/app.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
[x-cloak] {
    display: none;
}
```

This is my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

I have done thousands of npm run builds and npm installs, but nothing. I have followed the Tailwind instructions to install it, but nothing, the thing just cannot be loaded. I did all of the checks:

- The main file **resources/css/app.css** already existed
- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">` brings up a 404 in the Network tab of the dev console in Chrome when included in the code
- tailwind.config.js exists and is configured properly.

I have yet to find any simple documentation to instruct me how I can do this properly and I do not understand what I missed, I followed all the instructions and double-checked everything. The website is working without a problem other than loading TailWind and Im frustratingly out of ideas as to how I can solve this issue.  In my /public/ folder I have this:

- /public/build/assets/app-476eb4f6.js
- /public/build/assets/app-993c10f5.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of things. If you are using Laravel 10, the default compiler is now Vite, and not Mix. So that will mean that in your layout, you'll have a line for something like this below, rather than the traditional `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">`.

```html
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

So this is where your styling is coming from, which means you will not need `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">` at all.

Secondly, you mention that running `npm run dev` won't stop in the terminal - and that is expected, as with Vite, the `npm run dev` command is kind of like `npm run watch` from the old days when using Mix. In addition to this change, Vite has some other goodies baked into it as well, but that's why you'll see it running forever - it's ment to do that. I suggest reading here from the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#vite-or-mix

Finally though - the issue with not seeing any styles is because you haven't compiled them yet. If you run `npm run build`, you'll build all your assets, and this is what you'll do when you're done - before deploying into production. While developing locally, you can use `npm run dev` (the forever running process) to make it rebuild the CSS whenever you change a file (Tailwind only compiles the CSS classes you actually use, so rebuilding it is needed when you add new classes that you haven't used before).

Comment: Okay, that worked like a charm. I was led to believe that Tailwind is automatically configured with Livewire, and I had alot of trouble finding out how to load assets, but with  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles it was made pretty easy. Thank you

Comment: Tailwind is configured with Jetstream (Livewire does not include Tailwind), but like Mix, you'll need to compile it. Vite is also much faster, so that's a bonus